# Center a linearlayout vertically in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView and I am trying to center the L/L vertically.

Here is my markup

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/black">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_name_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:background="@color/titlered"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <Button android:id="@+id/place_order_btn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/startactivitybutton"
            android:textColor="@color/brown"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/StartActivity_PlaceOrder"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/past_orders_btn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/startactivitybutton"
            android:textColor="@color/brown"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/StartActivity_PastOrders"/>

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

It is the LinearLayout with the 2 buttons I am trying to center vertically.

I tried setting the outer LinearLayout to layout_height=fill_parent but the IDE moans because it is in a ScrollView.

Comment: Can you provide a simple diagram of what you are trying to accomplish? You've also got a textview in there not just 2 buttons. Are you trying to center the outer linearlayout in respect to the entire view height? Fyi `fill_parent` is deprecated in favor of `match_parent`.

Comment: there are lots of nesting in your layout, it will decrease the performance of the app. And when it comes to your question, i still dont understand wat do you mean center_vertical in vertically oriented L/L. Thats literally not possible. If you could exactly tell what you are trying to achieve, we might suggest a better layout structure. something with Relativr Layout may be.

Comment: The Linear Layout after the TextView should be vertically centered in the remaining space of the current view